# How do I make sure that a connected USB device gets enumerated before starting "init" process in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am working on a Linux based embedded product that has a non-removable USB device. 
Sometimes during bootup the device gets enumerated after starting "init" process. I need to make sure that this device should get enumerated by Linux kernel before starting "init" process.

Please provide your views to handle such situation. Suggestions for changes in Kernel/User space are welcome.

Comment: You need to built-in all the necessary frameworks and drivers.

Comment: There are some kernel command line options to wait for certain critical devices to show up. `rootwait` waits for the root device to show up. `resumewait` waits for the resume device to show up (if used). Those are useful when the root device or resume device are on an MMC or USB storage device.

Answer (score 0):

Linux deliberately doesn't wait until hardware initialization is complete.

I suggest creating a udev entry that runs a specific executable for when your USB becomes available.

Comment: First part needs elaboration. I don't believe kernel has such mechanism by default.